Jboss application deployed in openshift container
I have a Jboss web application deployed in the Openshift container,
As per the router configuration in openshift, If we want to disable the sticky session then we need to set the following two configuration
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-specific-annotations_route-configuration
Router Configuration:
haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies -> true
haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance -> roundrobin for load balancing the request.
Issue Description:
But when I enable the 'disable_cookies' flag, the following 'principal' gets null. (Generally it will have the User Principal details)
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;     
Principal principal = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();

Because of the authentication information (UserPrincipal) being null, I get the below WARNING in the logs and the SAML request goes on loop.
WARN [org.keycloak.adapters.saml.profile.webbrowsersso.WebBrowserSsoAuthenticationHandler] (default task-3) Adapter obtained LoginResponse, however containers session is not aware of sending any request. This may be because the session cookies created by container are not properly configured with SameSite settings. Refer to KEYCLOAK-14103 for more details.
NOTE: I tried setting the 'samesite' cookiee as default and removed the secure flag in the standalone.xml
I tried doing lots of analysis in different documents but didn't help, Could anyone help on

why the authentication (UserPrincipal) becomes null when I set the 'disable_cookies' flag as 'true'?
If it comes as Null, why the keycloak is not accepting the request?

